# Python function os.listdir doesnt show all files in directory

Tags: python, file

Hi I'm trying load couple of files  with `os.listdir` but it skips several files.

Format of files in directiy is:

```
a_0.csv
a_1.csv
a_2.csv
  ·
  ·
  ·
a_25.csv
```

But the `os.listdir` only take file *0,1,10,11..* 
File with numbers *3,4,5...* aren't in in output object.

And here is my function:

```
def best_fit_from_attemp(self):
    arr =[]
    for i in os.listdir(self.path_to_files):
        print("i",i)
        if i[0] == 'f' and  i[1] == 'i' and i[2] == 't':
            print("searching for smallest number... ",i)
            arr.append(self.find_min_fitness(i))
```

Output:

```
i fitness_gen_0.csv
searching for smallest number...  fitness_gen_0.csv
i fitness_gen_1.csv
searching for smallest number...  fitness_gen_1.csv
i fitness_gen_10.csv
searching for smallest number...  fitness_gen_10.csv
i fitness_gen_11.csv
searching for smallest number...  fitness_gen_11.csv
```

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the correct directory?

Comment: Are you truncating further output? It seems you get the first files only (ordered due to string therefore 10 appears before 3)

Comment: Beside the point, but you could replace `i[0] == 'f' and  i[1] == 'i' and i[2] == 't'` with `i.startswith('fit')`. BTW welcome to SO! check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Thank for warm welcoming. Yes path to the directory is right. Unfortunately when it finds file `a_1` it jump to `a_10` and the  when it comes to 20 the sequence is *19,2,20,21*. It is really odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the filenames are all there, just not in the order you expect.

The file names are strings.  They are sorted according to string-sorting logic: imagine replacing every 0 with an `a`, every 1 with a `b`, every 2 with a `c` and so on, and now think about how the strings would be ordered alphabetically. Ordinary string sorting doesn't know that we like to write numbers with the least-significant-digit **last**. In ordinary string sorting, it really does go `1`, then `10`, then `11`—that's analogous to ordering the strings `b`, then `ba`, then `bb`, which is the correct dictionary ordering. It will go on for a long time before it gets to anything starting with `3` (analogously, the words in the dictionary that start with `d` come much later than anything starting with `b`).

You could investigate algorithms/packages that do "natural sorting". Or, the greatly preferable best practice would be simply to fix your file naming convention to start with: ensure that the numbers embedded in your filenames all have the same number of digits, with leading zeros where necessary (`001`, `002`, etc).

Comment: Thanks. You was right. The files was there but I had implemented restriction when is found last file with number 25 then the subroutines ends. Just for sure output was `0, 1, 10, 11,..., 19, 2, 20, 21, ..., 24, 3, 4, ...`

Answer (score 0):

I would be pretty sure that the problem lies in the function `self.find_min_fitness(i)`. Some parts in it must cause the program to break after listing the first couple of files.

The files are sorted by name by `os.listdir()`. It prefers `1`over `2` when listing the files, that's why all the filenames starting with `1` are listed first.

As a solution: Maybe try and comment out this one line where `self.find_min_fitness(i)` is called and see whether the problem still occurs

Answer (score 0):

This seems questionable.

```
self.find_min_fitness(i)
```

Well I would suggest you try something like this.

Below directory contains a list of files numbered.

```
files = os.listdir("C:/Users/Danish/Documents/JavaScriptPrimerRepo/MyJSCodes")

for i in files:
    print(i)
```

This is the sample output below.

```
00_BlankPage.html
01_DataType.html
02_LinkingExternalJsfile.html
02_Script.js
03_VariableMutation_cohersion.html
04_Operators.html
05_SampleCodeCalculatingBMI.html
```

NOTE: I stored the result in separate variable before iterating and importantly fileName starts with number first.